# Log in with email address only

Tags: 8, users

I am looking for a concrete way to *only* allow logging in with email address only in Drupal 8.

I have seen Login Email and Login EmailUsername modules, but *both* still allow for username login as well as email.

I am looking only for email.

So far, I have come up with this in the interim - but something is not quite right. While I can trigger a form error, the form still submits and authentication is called. It should not submit if the entered value does not resemble an email address:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['name']['#type'] = 'email';
  $form['name']['#title'] = t('Email Address');
  $form['name']['#description'] = t('Enter your email address.');
  $form['name']['#element_validate'][] = 'mymodule_login_validate_user';
  $form['pass']['#description'] = t('Enter the password that accompanies your email address.');
}

/**
 * Custom validation handler for the form login.
 *
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 * @return bool
 */
function mymodule_login_validate_user(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $email_input = $form_state->getValue('name');

  if (!\Drupal::service('email.validator')->isValid($email_input)) {
    $form_state->setError($element, 'Please enter a valid email address.');
  }
}
```

I am also overriding the core `user.auth` service with my own - I will be generating usernames based on factors about the user (fetching information from a remote AMS).

Is there any way to avoid username in Drupal 8?

edit: Users cannot register on the Drupal site, and forgot password will be replaced with a link to the external AMS system.

Comment: `$form['name']['#element_validate'][] ` never seen it done like this before, the way I know its: `$form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_login_validate_user';` and remove the `&$element` param from your call back function.

Comment: so use `function mymodule_login_validate_user($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {`

Comment: So try it like this and see if it works.

Comment: I got it - `email_registration` module was still enabled (was checking it out) causing me trouble. I am providing my own UserAuth service, so now with just the above, only email login is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [Login with Email only](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_onlyemail) should solve that. At least worth a look how they managed to do that.

> This simple Drupal 8 module allows users to log in **exclusively** with
>   their email address from the standard login form.
>
> **Setup:**
>
> Just enable the module.
>
> **Recommended Modules:**
>
> This module is based on the Login Email or Username module:
>   https://www.drupal.org/project/login_emailusername